# MDX Year on Year Sales by Months

Tags: sql, mdx, mondrian

I'm stuck on a MDX query, I'm trying to retrieve the following results:

```
                          [Time].[2009]       [Time].[2010]
[Time].[Months].Members   [Measures].[Sales]  [Measures].[Sales]
```

So I would like to compare the sales which were in 2009 against 2010 by month.

In terms of a chart I would have two series one for 2009 and 2010, the y axis would be the sales value and the x axis would be the month.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT {[Time].[2009], [Time].[2010]} ON COLUMNS,
[Time].[Months].Members ON ROWS
FROM [SalesProductIndicator] WHERE [Measures].[Sales]
```

It gives me this error:

```
Mondrian Error:Dimension '[Time]' appears in more than one independent axis.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT {[Time].[2009], [Time].[2010]} ON 0,
    [Time].[Months].Members ON 1
    FROM [Your Cube Name] WHERE [Measures].[Sales]

I based that on this query (below) that I've tested on the Adventure Works sample cube from Miscrosoft:

```
SELECT {[Ship Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2002], [Ship Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2003]} ON 0,
[Ship Date].[Month of Year].Members ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works] WHERE [Measures].[Sales Amount]
```

UPDATE:

Based on your query I'm not sure why it is working without specifiying a hierarchy on your cube query (like [Time].[2010] instead of [Time].[Hierarchy Name].[2010]) but could you try this:

```
SELECT EXISTS([Time].Members, {[Time].[2009], [Time].[2010]}) ON COLUMNS, 
[Time].[Months].Members ON ROWS 
FROM [SalesProductIndicator] WHERE [Measures].[Sales]
```

Thanks

Comment: Jojo,

Looks good! How would I include more than one measure?

Comment: This seems to give me this error:

Mondrian Error:Dimension '[Time]' appears in more than one independent axis.

Comment: @schone - what I do when I query multiple measures is I place them as set on the column (0). For your error are you sure you provided the right (full) name of the 2009 and 2010 member and the cube name? Could you post your new query. Thanks

Comment: @jojo,

I have added my query to the original question. Yep I provided the right name as I can take out the Time dimension on the row and replace it with the Sales measure and it works.

Anymore ideas?

Comment: @schone - I wonder why its working with your cube query that you don't specify a hierarchy name on specifying a member. You could try my updated answer.

Comment: @jojo,

That still doesnt work - I have created a second Time dimension in the meantime but that isn't probably considered "best" practice.

I also had problems where the [Time].[Months].Members was outputting every date/time in the table - should I be adding a WHERE clause for both the years in question?